# Join column from other dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have got 2 dataframes:
d1 columns: ['Text', 'Date', 'Date_with_affect'] - with Id as index:

> 89, 'Hello', 2018-03-05, 2018-03-06

d2 columns: ['Price', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Vol.', 'Change'] - with Date set as 
index

> 2018-03-06, 12, 13, 14, 11, 0, 0.5

I would like to add new column to the d1 dataframe that will be a 'Change' column from d2 by "*Date_with_affect*" matching the "*Date*" from d2.
So the result would be:

> 89, 'Hello', 2018-03-05, 2018-03-06, 0.5

And if date is not in d2 then should pick the next day.
What is the easiest way to that? 
I tried to do that but I guess that it is completly wrong.

```
d1["Change"] = d2[d1["Date_with_affect"]].Change
```

Comment: could you paste the output of `d1.head()` and `d2.head()` to illustrate the data contained in the two dataframes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this case I think you can use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) (also, I assuming your date is datetime format. If not, try to converting it using `pd.to_datetime`):

```
pd.merge_asof(
   d1,
   d2.reset_index()[['Date','Change']],
   left_on='Date_with_affect',
   right_on='Date'
)
```

Comment: All about that aesthetic.

Comment: I get error: "ValueError: left keys must be sorted".Both dates are datatimes

Comment: @AlaGłowacka using sort_values before merge